# How to make a branch and revert the main branch to some point?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have a main branch, called "dog", I commit there every day. Today my boss said that I made a mistake, I had to create another branch "cat" a week ago and put all my commits there during the week.

Well, now it's too late.

Is it possible to do it now: to create a branch as if a week ago and move all commits there, so that current "dog" looks like no one committed to it for the entire week?

Comment: Did you already pushed the commits to the remote?

Comment: Yes I did, I pushed them all...

Comment: Ok then go with the @Travo's answer, but be aware if you push force you will destroy all the remote history as well and other developer will be influenced by this.

Comment: Yup, @ckruczek is correct, if others are using the same repository, then it's not safe to --force things. You should consult with them beforehand.

Comment: Or in addition, you can revert all the commits from where you have the 'bug' and push them.

Comment: No, I am the only user of the branch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my theoretical course of action:

**Step 1:** Rename current branch from `dog` to `cat`.

`git branch -m <oldname> <newname>`

which turns into

`git branch -m dog cat`

**Step 2:** Create a new branch `dog` from the last commit you want there to be.

For that, get the last commit you want the `dog` branch to have and do the following:

`git branch dog <sha1-of-commit>`

OR

`git checkout -b dog <sha1-of-commit>`

If you have already pushed to origin, you might have to `--force` some things.